# set methods in Java

Tags: java, set

Could anubody explain how to use set methods? Problem:

```
class Sonum {
   private int prior;
   public Sonum(int prior) {
      this.prior = prior;
   }
   public int getPrior() {
      return prior;
   }
   public void setPrior(int prior) {
      this.prior = prior;
   }

class Tel {
   // Please explain how can I set the value for prior? (for example 2)
}
```

Comment: Forget to use the coveted `homework` tag?

Answer (score 3):

Well, first you need an instance of `Sonum` on which you want to set the `prior` value. For example:

```
class Test {
  public void foo() {
    Sonum sonum = new Sonum(5);
    // Use it with a prior of 5
    // ...
    sonum.setPrior(10);
    // Now use it with a prior of 10
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sonum mySonum = new Sonum(1); //prior is currently 1
mySonum.setPrior(2); //now prior is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a deep breath. The [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html). Read it. You will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Refer

Creating Objects & Using Objects

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 0):

"Setter methods" aren't magic. They're just regular methods. You need an instance of that class, and then you can call the methods on it. Just like any other Java object.

Comment: Depends just a bit on how you define "magic".  Their being part of the nearly universal way do properties in Java, they have gotten a bit of special support in RAD environments and frameworks of all kinds.  But you are right in saying that at the language level, they're just regular methods.

Comment: The're not special in, say, the sense that they are in C#

Answer (score 0):

set method deal with a private value that we would like to prevent the direct way to him using our client, therefor there are get \ set method.

The biggest advantage of get \ set methods is the control ability !
We can for example control a minimum age when we want to set an age, and many other simple examples.

Example:

```
setAge (int age)
{
    if ( age < 0 )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Wrong age !!" );
    }
}
```

Now I think you can easily understand this HW :)

Comment: I think I should leave this here: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html (Why getter and setter methods are evil by Alan Holub)